# How can I stop a Device.StartTimer () when I change the page and when my app is moved to the background? and correct use of MessagingCenter

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timer

I'm trying to create a ListView which refreshes its content every 5 seconds, for this I'm using a Device.StartTimer (), I've managed to make it work, but I've noticed that Device.StartTimer () is global to the application and what put in the callback is still running even when I change the page or change the application on my device.

My question is: How can I get the timer to stop when I change the page and change the application?

So far I have had some progress, which is that using OnAppearing, OnDisAppearing and the MessagingCenter I have managed to change the page when the timer stops.

With this implementation, I am worried that I really do not know if I am really unsubscribing from the message, it is the right place, I would like someone to tell me about it too.

Below fragments of my View and my ViewModel:

View:

```
public partial class MonitoringView : TabbedPage
{

    MonitoringViewModel context = new MonitoringViewModel();

    public MonitoringView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = context;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing");
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing");
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MonitoringTabsViewModel : Notificable
{
    public string IdCode { get; set; }

    public bool InPage { get; set; }

    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PcData> sensors;

    public ObservableCollection<PcData> Sensors
    {
        get { return sensors; }
        set
        {
            sensors = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MonitoringTabsViewModel(string idCode, string description)
    {
        IdCode = idCode;
        Description = description;
        LoadSensors(idCode);
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing", (sender) =>
        {
            InPage = true;
        });
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing", (sender) =>
        {
            InPage = false;
        });
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimerCallBack);
    }

    private bool TimerCallBack()
    {
        if (InPage)
        {
            RefreshSensors(IdCode);
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async void LoadSensors(string idCode)
    {
        Sensors = new ObservableCollection<PcData>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCurrentStatusDeviceAsync(idCode));
    }

    private async void RefreshSensors(string idCode)
    {
        Sensors = null;
        Sensors = new ObservableCollection<PcData>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCurrentStatusDeviceAsync(idCode));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

> With this implementation, I am worried that I really do not know if I
>   am really unsubscribing from the message

To test whether you really have unsubscribed from the message, you can add a `breakpoint` to the `RefreshSensors` function when you are debugging the app which is connecting with VS.

Then you can send a message the same as `MessagingCenter.Send<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing");` in another page after you leaving your `MonitoringView` to see if the `breakpoint` has been triggered, if not, it means you have unsubscribed from the message successfully.

And in you code of `TimerCallBack`, I think you `should not` unsubscribe the message here. You will never receive the message when you come back from another page since you have unsubscribed them. You can unsubscribe the message when this page is `onDestory`.

```
 private bool TimerCallBack()
    {
        if (InPage)
        {
            RefreshSensors(IdCode);
            //MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also, you should put `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimerCallBack);` inside `onappearing` message.

```
public MonitoringTabsViewModel(string idCode, string description)
{
    IdCode = idCode;
    Description = description;
    LoadSensors(idCode);
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing", (sender) =>
    {
        InPage = true;
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimerCallBack);

    });
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing", (sender) =>
    {
        InPage = false;
    });
}
```

Once the `OnAppearing` message has been received, the `Device.StartTimer` will run in the page and once the `OnDisAppearing` message has been received, the callback will return false and `Device.StartTimer` will stop.